# How to modify codecoverage.config to specify which module to include during VS2012 dynamic code coverage?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, customization, code-coverage

I am trying to use VS2012 dynamic code coverage tool to do code coverage analysis for my application.
I find an example that I can use it like follows:

CodeCoverage.exe collect /output:C:\test.coverage c:\aut.exe

This works well however, my aut.exe will load many dlls and I simply don't want to get code coverage information for every dll. So I need to modify the CodeCoverage.config file in VS2012 dynamic code coverage Tools folder to only include some dlls I want.

I look at the config file, it looks like:

```
<SymbolSearchPaths />
    <!--
    The module include/exclude list by the full path from where the module loaded.
    Entries in this list are case-insensitive.
  -->
<ModulePaths />
```

This file is a little bit different with the previous .runsettings file. I tried adding following code in the config file:

```
<ModulePaths>
     <Include>
         <!-- Include modules of interest, by their name / path -->
             <ModulePath>SomeSpecial.dll</ModulePath>
         </Include>
         <Exclude>
              <!—- Do not specify any excludes. Anything not included will get excluded -->
         </Exclude>
</ModulePaths>
```

But it did not work. I guess the grammar here is a little different with the .runsetting file.

So can anyone guide me on how to modify the codecoverage.config file to only include specific dlls for code coverage?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally solved the problem myself...

Actually there is a way to only include some dlls for code coverage. I should use regular expressions when defining the module path for include.

For example:

```
<ModulePaths>
     <Include>
        <ModulePath>.*SomeSpecial\.dll$</ModulePath>
        <ModulePath>.*Special\.dll$</ModulePath>
     </Include>
</ModulePaths>
```

The key is add ".*" before your dll name and add "\" before "." because the node for Module path here only allows for regular expression.  Using this method, I successfully include the dlls I want for code coverage.

Comment: This got me too.  I didn't read the xml-comments above the settings.  "Each element in the list is a regular expression (ECMAScript syntax)."